# Pivot MySQL How to

Tags: mysql, pivot, pivot-table

I'm new to MySQL, on MSSQL exists the pivot function... i've been searching on how to do this in MySQL but stil don't get it.
i have the following query:

```
select c001adusec as A, count(distinct c001numped) as B, 
case month(d001fecpag) when 1 then 'ENE' when 2 then 'FEB' when 3 then 'MAR' when 4 then 'ABR' when 5 then 'MAY' end as C
FROM AT001 where  year(d001fecpag)=2015 and c001cvecli='INDP3' and c001tipope=1 
GROUP BY c001adusec,month(d001fecpag)
```

that gives me this result:

```
 A     B     C
240   13     ENE
240   12     FEB
240   13     MAR
240   13     ABR
240   2      MAY
800   2      MAR
```

but i want it this way:

```
Mes     240 800

Ene     13  0
Feb     12  0
Mar     13  2
Abr     13  0
May     2   0
```

can anyone help me ??

Comment: There are loads of questions about this. [Here's one of them](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674786/mysql-pivot-table)

Comment: but this is for static columns. i need for dynamic :/

Comment: mysql is not your friend in that case. sorry